# Postgres foreign key on parent table including all child tables

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 Tables: Animal_Type, Horse, Cat and Amount. Animal_Type is just a baseclass for Horse and Cat and is never instantiated directly. Horse also has the attributes 'ridable' and 'speed' while cat has the attribute 'is_tame'. Amount just counts the amount of animals of a type (I have to do it this way, for a complicated reason).
Now I would like Amount to reference Animal_Type. The problem is, that a foreign key of a baseclass only looks for direct instances of the baseclass, which do not exist.

So How can I reference the baseclass in a table in postgres while including all child tables?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) "*A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that [...] foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children*" - so you can't do what you want.

Comment: Yeah I saw that article, i just really hoped a feature or workaround would have been implemented by now

Comment: If there was, it would have been documented in the manual

Comment: Simple "work around": Populate the animal_type table with the appropriate values, then create  the FK.

Comment: I just created faux inheritance using FK relations. Does the job